# pybossa - info column in result table

Tags: pybossa

I don't understand how does info column in result table been filled.

Based on my testing, every time a project is completed, a few lines will be added into the result table of pybossa db.

However, no matter what I do, the info column is empty.

This is causing some issues in the web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PYBOSSA result table will create always an empty result for the completed task (and its associated task runs). Why we do this? Because we don't want to force anyone to store their results in PYBOSSA. However, if you want, you will benefit from the full text search API of PYBOSSA.

For the result table, you can use the webhooks solution. The webhooks will send a POST message to a micro service (that we offer as well as open source [here](https://github.com/Scifabric/webhooks)) that will download the task and task runs, perform a statistical analysis (whatever you want to do), and then, if you want, update the empty result that PYBOSSA created for you.

We are using this solution in several projects, allowing us to basically do real-time analysis within PYBOSSA. Take a look at our Spanish project https://sralergeno.pybossa.com that integrates not only webhooks, but also our web push notifications systems. This feature, enables us to get phone notifications when a new product has been classified as gluten free :D

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I'm able to get this micro-service named webhooks app running. However, I'm not sure what exactly should be done to let Pybossa send POST requests to this micro-service. I don't see any related info in pybossa docs or pybossa RESTful API section.

Comment: Anyway, I created another topic regarding this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45606567/how-to-configure-webhook-in-pybossa